# Unable to upgrade Eclipse from 4.5.1 (Mars.1) to 4.5.2 (Mars.2)

Tags: eclipse

When running Help > Check for updates, Eclipse finds the 4.5.2 update.
When updating, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=_Users_username_dev_tools_eclipses_eclipse4.5.1.mars_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.client,0.12.0.v20160425083245
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.model,0.12.0.v20160425083245
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.utils,0.12.0.v20160425083245
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.branding,1.0.15.v20160425-1638
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.core,1.0.15.v20160425-1638
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.ui,1.0.15.v20160425-1638
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.gradle.toolingapi,2.13.0.v20160425083245
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.buildship,1.0.15.v20160425-1638
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.stsmigration,1.0.15.v20160425-1638

I did remove the Gradle plugin from Help > Installation Details > Installed Software, but I still see Gradle references in Help > Installation Details > Plug-Ins.

Extract of Help > Installation Details > Configuration:

> com.gradleware.tooling.client (0.6.1.v201509101146) "toolingclient" [Resolved]
>   com.gradleware.tooling.model (0.6.1.v201509101146) "toolingmodel" [Resolved]
>   com.gradleware.tooling.utils (0.6.1.v201509101146) "toolingutils" [Resolved]

This is on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by doing:

1. Help > Install new software > Available Software Sites > Add a trailing slash to URLs that don't have one
2. Check for updates again.

This solution was taken from item #2 of this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/2223027

Comment: Worked for me, trying to install `m2eclipse-scala`.